# Титул человек в телеграм

Tags: python, telebot

Всем доброго времени суток, хотел бы спросить такую вещь, как можно присвоить титул человеку типо как на фото ниже.
[image: пример титула]

Использую библиотеку pyTelegramBotAPI,
Такая возможность есть у бота Silent Bot, но не знаю на чем он написан, хочу вот узнать как можно так присвоить титул